# Fastest way for data input into StreamPlot function

Tags: plotting, graphics, performance-tuning

I'm interested in looking at graphing the phase portraits of 2x2 autonomous ODEs, and I'm using the `StreamPlot` function.

Here is one simple example:

```
StreamPlot[{-y, -2 x}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
```

I'm finding it very tedious to continue typing `, {x,-5,5}, {-5,5}` etc. as part of every separate plot I construct. Is there some faster way to input my range? I don't want to have to rely on ctrl c ctrl v etc.

I'm sorry if this is a silly question!

Comment: Make a button with the appropriate placeholders, perhaps?

Comment: Silly that I didn't think of that, thank you!

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Thank you! This community is very intimidating because everyone seems like an expert and I feel I can't contribute anything yet, but I'll do those suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps,

```
ClearAll[inpField]
inpField[arg_, fs_: 5] := InputField[arg, FieldSize -> fs, Background -> Yellow, 
  Appearance -> "Frameless"]

Interpretation[{f = {-y, -2 x}, xmin = 0, xmax = 1, ymin = 0, ymax = 1},
 Panel@Row[{"StreamPlot[", inpField[Dynamic[f], 12],
    ", \n ", Invisible["StreamPlo"], "{x, ", 
    inpField[Dynamic[xmin]], ",", inpField[Dynamic[xmax]], 
    "}, \n ", Invisible["StreamPlo"], "{y, ", 
    inpField[Dynamic[ymin]], ",", inpField[Dynamic[ymax]], "}]"}],
 StreamPlot[f, {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax}]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Fill-in the input fields and `Shift+Enter`:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]